# How do I copy the first field of the first line into succeeding lines?

Tags: regex, sed

Trying to get this expression to work, can someone look at it and tell me how far off I am?

I'm trying to get info in line 1 to propagate to other blank lines.

```
Line 1 = "1234, type"
Line 2..99 = ", type"
```

Result: Line 1.. = "1234, type"

This is the expression

```
sed -i -R -n '{(^[^,]{});x;n;^,;s/^.{}/\1/;x;p;x;p}' SedExit.txt > Str.txt
```

Comment: @potong (and others) may be able to help you with a sed solution, but tagging with awk will get you a certain, easy to understand solution. Also, please edit your question to show required output. Hard to tell what you mean by 'info from line 1 to propagate'. which info? Good luck.

Comment: So you want the first field of the latest line that has one to be prepended to the lines that are missing one, right?  That'd be much easier in awk (or perl, etc.) than sed.  Using the hold buffer with partial-line data is tricky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case you're interested in an `awk`-based solution, and assuming my interpretation of your request in my comment above is correct:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } $1 { last = $1 } !$1 { $1 = last } { print }' SedExit.txt
```

**EDIT**: brief explanation -

`-F,` tells awk to use comma as the input field separator; it will automatically split
      lines on comma and make the individual fields available as $1, $2, etc.  ($0 is the whole line)

`BEGIN {` code `}` runs the code in braces once at the beginning of the awk run, before any input is processed.

`OFS = ","` sets the output field separator to comma, to match the input. That lets us modify the fields directly and still get comma-separated output, instead of having to reconstruct the whole line in our code.

The rest of the code is run once per line of input:

`$1 { last = $1 }`     The first `$1` is a condition that must be met for the next block of code to be executed: if that field of the current line is true (non-empty), then the block is run.  The block saves a copy of that field in a new variable called `last'.

So if there's anything before the first comma, we remember it for later use.

`!$1 { $1 = last }`  The condition here is negated, so this block will only run if the first field is empty.  In that case, we copy the other way, and set the first field to the value of `last`.  Hopefully we have previously seen a line that matched the first block and set `last` to something, or this is not useful.

`{ print }`  There's no condition here, so the code is run on every line, and it just prints it out.  The output will incorporate our modification to $1, if applicable.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the feedback, ill take a look at the Awk solution, i'm happy with what ever solution so long as it gets the job done.

Since I cant find a way to edit my question, I was looking for the following

Line 1 = "1234, Type" Line 2.. = ",Type"

Result = Line 1.. = "1234,Type"

Comment: That didn't work off the bat, would you mind tossing in some "how it works" on that snippet for me please?

Reading the awk --help is light on details.

Comment: My Mistake, that did work, thank you.

Gee you guys are great you know that?

Comment: Thanks.  I added a "how it works" snippet anyway, in case you find it helpful.

Comment: For code golf fun: `awk -F, '$1{l=$1}!$1{$1=l}1' OFS=, SedExit.txt`

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem Statement

You want to copy the first field of the first line into the first field of each succeeding line, preferably using sed.

#### Solution

Store the first field in a variable, and then perform your sed expression on a line range.

```
FIELD1=$(head -n1 /tmp/foo | cut -d, -f1)
sed "2,$ s/^.*,/$FIELD1,/" /tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^,/!{h;b};G;s/\(.*\)\n\([^,]*\).*/\2\1/' file
```

Explanation:

- If the line does not begin with a comma, save that line in the hold space (HS) and break i.e. no further processing but print the line. `/^,/!{h;b}`
- If the line does begin with a comma, append a newline and the contents of the HS to the pattern space (PS). `G`
- Prepend the first field that was in the HS, upto the first comma, to the current line and delete all other remainders. `s/\(.*\)\n\([^,]*\).*/\2\1/`